# exec: : not found - error while installing python3 with homebrew on pop os linux

Tags: python-3.x, linux

i was trying to install python3 on pop os! linux through homebrew

this is the erorr i faced :

file:///home/hawkeye/.linuxbrew/Library/brew.sh: line 177: exec: : not found

pls help

Comment: what is output of following command `which -a ruby`?

Answer (score 4):

first check if ruby istalled or not

```
which -a ruby
```

if not then run

```
sudo apt install ruby-full
```

If that doesn't help then try these commands

```
 1. export PATH=$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH
 2. hash -r
```